# How to display an object in other objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having trouble displaying data in a table. I'm trying to loop through an object inside and object inside an array. I want to show source, accountId, name, and sourceId in my table.

[image]

```html
<tbody class="network_Audience"  v-for="(value, item) in networkAudiences" :key="item">
     <tr v-for="(data, index) in item" :key="index">
           <td class="text-center data-column">
               {{ data.source }}
           </td>
           <td class="text-center data-column">
               {{ data.accountId }}
           </td>
           <tdlass="text-center data-column"> 
               {{ data.name }} 
           </td>
           <td lass="text-center data-column"> 
                {{ data.sourceId }} 
           </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I get the information?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="networkNumber in networkAudiences">
    <div v-for="dataArray in networkNumber">
      <div v-for="objectData in dataArray">
        {{ objectData.id }}
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      networkAudiences: {
      //  networkNumber
        52: {
        //  dataArray
          data: [
            //  objectData x2
            { id: 789 },
            { id: 790 }
          ],
        },
        53: {
          data: [
            { id: 300 },
            { id: 301 }
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is [a demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1UttuwjAM/RUrT5sEDRtCG1U3CWnP+4FlD6UNI4w2kZPCpqr/PgdoGhi0L3Z8jn18adnCmGTXSJayzMnKbHMnX0UtXFaqHezGK40vgtXS7TV+vzfVUiKoGk4Pi6ZUsi6kFYxIQN8ZrcxdvkDMfyPKMUfAXzD0ciML90Y8Twn8CA7QtjDAElVC14VcnJINmdcIvNcVIr2V8bhf+jNboDKOPPljNDoo5Spvtg5aT/Na7u6PNgBK12Dde/BvHukQApg9kgucX4wgxI/JU/jwmKHnKE5NgypTeHqeQzfysGECV3HzCXS3YZ+jwesiezY90x10XSsxnVCJiBtHHiBs5Ha53jpAvUNGxk87YCOmKr+EcZWbZGN1TQd6kCZOATq5IFYwumDvC7Z2ztiUc7sq/FlvbKLxi5OVYFM7VclE2mq8RL23EimxYIfyVJ11f1qd510=).